# What are some of the known fungi with heat resistant spores

Tags: mycology, thermophilia

Are there any fungi whose spores can survive 100+ degrees for 15 minutes and grow in a sugar-deprived medium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Sterflinger, some black yeasts may qualify: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10081587

> Rock inhabiting meristematic fungi are extremely tolerant against high
>   temperatures, desiccation and osmotic stress. Their temperature
>   tolerance increases with increasing dehydration of the fungal thallus.
>   Air dried mycelia of black yeasts stand temperatures up to 120 degrees
>   C for at least 0.5 hours

More recently, Suryanarayanan et al. (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21872180) have published the discovery of several fungal environmental isolates able to survive dry heat sterilization for 2h at 100+ degrees C. Growth testing was done on Potatao Dextrose Agar (PDA).

> Among 25 species of Ascomycota isolated from leaf litter, nine were
>   able to grow after incubation in a drying oven for 2 h at 100 °C; the
>   spores of two of these species survived 2 h incubation at 110 °C, and
>   one survived exposure to 115 °C for 2 h." (...) Craphigera and Phoma sp.
>   survived 2 h incubation at 110 °C; the conidia of Bartalinia sp. were
>   the most resistant and survived exposure to 115 °C for 2 h

The isolates which survived at least 2h at 100 C were:

- Bartalinia sp. (NFCCI 2307)
- Chaetomella raphigera (NFCCI 2308)
- Curvularia sp. isolate 2 (NFCCI 2311)
- Drechslera halodes (NFCCI 2312)
- Leptosphaerulina sp.
- Pestalotiopsis sp. isolate 1 (NFCCI 2309)
- Pestalotiopsis sp. isolate 2 (NFCCI 2313)
- Phoma sp. (NFCCI 2310)
- Pithomyces sp. (IMTECH 9398)